# What is difference between 'transfer learning' and 'domain adaptation'?

Tags: deep-learning, terminology, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning, domain-adaptation

Is there any difference between 'transfer learning' and 'domain adaptation'?

I don't know about context, but my understanding is that we have some dataset 1 and train on it, after which we have another dataset 2 for which we want to adapt our model without retraining from scratch, for which 'transfer learning' and 'domain adaptation' help solve this problem.

According to the field of Convolutional Neural Networks:

- By 'transfer learning' I mean 'finetuning' [[1]](http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/)
- In this case [[2]](http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v37/ganin15.pdf) it's unsupervised, but should 'domain adaptation' always be unsupervised?

Comment: [A Survey on Transfer Learning](https://www.cse.ust.hk/~qyang/Docs/2009/tkde_transfer_learning.pdf) by Pan et. al, 2009 provides some insight. They categorize domain adaptation as a type of transfer learning.

Answer (score 19):

It seems that there are some disagreement between researchers on what the difference between 'transfer learning' and 'domain adaptation' is.

From {0}:

> The notion of domain adaptation is closely related to transfer learning. Transfer learning is a general term that refers to a class of machine learning problems that involve different tasks or domains. In the literature, there isn't yet a standard definition of transfer learning. In some papers it's interchangeable with domain
>   adaptation.

From {1}:

[image]

---

References:

- {0} Li, Qi. "Literature survey: domain adaptation algorithms for natural language processing." Department of Computer Science The Graduate Center, The City University of New York (2012): 8-10. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2828982016930721315&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/532e/3d5b1b5807771b77cac60fe8594b506fcff9.pdf ; http://nlp.cs.rpi.edu/paper/qisurvey.pdf  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170330011959/http://nlp.cs.rpi.edu/paper/qisurvey.pdf))
- {1} Pan, Sinno Jialin, and Qiang Yang. "A survey on transfer learning." IEEE Transactions on knowledge and data engineering 22, no. 10 (2010): 1345-1359. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=17771403852323259019&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.158.4126&rep=rep1&type=pdf  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170329230306/http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.158.4126&rep=rep1&type=pdf)) (2.6k citations)

Answer (score 12):

From Hal Daume's article [1]:

> The standard classification setting is a input distribution p(X) and a
>   label distribution p(Y|X).  Domain adaptation: when p(X) changes
>   between training and test.  Transfer learning: when p(Y|X) changes
>   between training and test.
>
> In other words, in DA the input distribution changes but the labels
>   remain the same; in TL, the input distributions stays the same, but
>   the labels change.

1. https://nlpers.blogspot.com/2007/11/domain-adaptation-vs-transfer-learning.html  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170329220702/https://nlpers.blogspot.com/2007/11/domain-adaptation-vs-transfer-learning.html))

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].  It is preferred that answers are self-contained with proper citations.  If you were to use the information from your link to provide a reasonable answer to the question with the link for further reading, this would be a much improved answer.

Comment: I don't believe this explanation. I don't believe HAL here. What if both $p(Y|X)$ and $p(X)$ change at the same time?

Comment: I agree with @caveman. For many transfer learning scenarios that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

Throughout the literature on transfer learning, there is a number of terminology inconsistencies. Phrases such as transfer learning and domain adaptation are used to refer to similar processes. Domain adaptation is the process of adapting one or more source domains for the means of transferring information to improve the performance of a target learner. The domain adaptation process attempts to alter a source domain in an attempt to bring the distribution of the source closer to that of the target. In the Domain Adaptation setting the source and target domains have different marginal distributions p(X). According to Pan's survey, Transfer Learning is a broader term that can also include the case when there is a difference in the conditional distributions p(Y|X) of the source and target domains. In contrast, Daume discriminates the two terms [1], referring that Domain Adaptation is when p(X) changes between source and target and Transfer learning is when p(Y|X) changes between source and target domains.

1. https://nlpers.blogspot.com/2007/11/domain-adaptation-vs-transfer-learning.html

Comment: Would it be possible to add a citation for "Pan's survey"? I think it would make this answer more useful to future readers.

Comment: Pan, Sinno Jialin, and Qiang Yang. "A survey on transfer learning." IEEE Transactions on knowledge and data engineering 22, no. 10 (2010): 1345-1359. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=17771403852323259019&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.158.4126&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 3):

I think that "Transfer Learning" is a more general term, and "Domain Adaptation" is a scenario of "Transfer Learning".

[1] Transferable Attention for Domain Adaptation. http://ise.thss.tsinghua.edu.cn/~mlong/doc/transferable-attention-aaai19.pdf

Answer (score 0):

According to [1], domain adaptation is the transfer learning in NLP: "Transfer learning in the NLP domain is sometimes referred to as domain adaptation."

[1] Pan, S. J., and Q. Yang. “A Survey on Transfer Learning.” IEEE Transactions on Knowledge and Data Engineering 22, no. 10 (October 2010): 1345–59. https://doi.org/10.1109/TKDE.2009.191 or https://www.cse.ust.hk/~qyang/Docs/2009/tkde_transfer_learning.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It seems wikipedia has the most concise answer:

> Domain adaptation is a subcategory of transfer learning. In **domain
> adaptation**, the source and target domains all have the same feature
> space (but different distributions); in contrast, **transfer learning**
> includes cases where the target domain's feature space is different
> from the source feature space or spaces.

Here is the [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_adaptation#:%7E:text=Domain%20adaptation%20is%20a%20subcategory,source%20feature%20space%20or%20spaces.).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/321272)